# Stack of cards (Solitaire-like) in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android

How can I make the tableaus in a Solitaire-like game for Android?:

[image]

**EDIT: thanks to the comments fixed my attempt:**

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableauThreeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tableau23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ap"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tableau13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ad"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tableau03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ac"/>


    </FrameLayout>
```

It works, however doesn't seem like the best solution. What would be the correct way to do this? (Consider that I have to do 12 stacks because I'm building Cruel Solitaire: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruel_(solitaire) )

Comment: Reverse the order of the image views, aka put the last one on top and so on.

Comment: @ivan You're right. It's better now. Anyway I'll leave it open, considering the application I'm trying to do maybe there's a better way to do all of this

Comment: Maybe there is but this issue specifically was regarding the z-order, the views stack on top of each other in the order you put them in the xml.

Comment: My opinion regarding specifically making this stack (if you want to do it programatically) would be to make a custom view.

Comment: You could make a custom `View` extending `FrameLayout`. I think that it is a good and robust solution to use overlapping views, I see no problem with that. I would only recommend to use `setZ(float)` method to ensure that views overlap in correct order: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setZ(float)

Comment: you can make it by a custom `ItemDecoration` on a recyclerView